# How to make ContentControl listen to non-routed event inside its ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datatemplate

I have some reusable ContentControl, which acts as a pseudo-modal popup inside another view.
It is always there and only its visibility makes it appear or disappear.
When instantiated, within the ContentControl there will be a custom ContentTemplate, bound to some ViewModel and representing the content of the "modal popup".

```
<Dialogs:ModalDialog DialogHost="{Binding ElementName=layoutRoot, Mode=OneTime}"
                     Content="{Binding ViewModel.CurrentEditItem}"
                     IsShown="{Binding ViewModel.IsInEdit}">
  <Dialogs:ModalDialog.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ItemEditor:ItemEditorView />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Dialogs:ModalDialog.ContentTemplate>
</Dialogs:ModalDialog>
```

Now I want to reach the following: the root of the ContentTemplate (here: ItemEditorView) should implement the following interface.

```
public interface ICloseMe
{
  event EventHandler<EventArgs> CloseMe;
}
```

Whenever the CloseMe-Event is fired, the surrounding ModalDialog should be "closed" by setting its VisibilityProperty to Hidden.

The view within the popup (here ItemEditorView) should not care, whether it is shown in a ModalDialog or another context, i.e. it should not even know that such class exists. This excludes a walk through the Logical or Visual tree.
It shall only fire the CloseMe-Event, when Cancel/Save-Buttons are pressed.

Further, the mechanism should not be implemented/configured in the view instantiating the ModalDialog, the view should be as dumb as possible.

Instead, the "outer" ModalDialog should do the active part and listen to the CloseMe-event.
How can I implement this in a rather clean, MVVM-compliant way and without introducing unnecessary dependencies? Is there any event, occuring after a ContentTemplate is initialized, s.t. the ModalDialog could then evaluate, if the root of it extends ICloseMe?

Answer (score 0):

How about making the `ICloseMe` include a `Closed` property that you could setup a trigger against in the XAML?

Comment: Would be ok in a sense of not creating additional dependencies, but how will the ModalDialog be connected to the Closed-Property of the ItemEditorView then?